# A continous extension of the group of permutation matrices

Tags: matrices, representation-theory, lie-groups, orthogonal-matrices, permutation-matrices

For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the collection $\mathcal{P}_n$ of permutation matrices is obtained by permuting the rows of the $n \times n$ identity matrix. Under the operation of matrix multiplication, $\mathcal{P_n}$ is a subgroup of $\mathcal{G_n}$ -- the subgroup of  $n \times n$ orthogonal matrices $\mathcal{O}_n$ that keeps the vector $e = (1, \ldots, 1)^t \in \mathbb{R}^n$ fixed.

Note that $\mathcal{G_n} \cong \mathcal{O}_{n-1}$. Is $\mathcal{G_n}$ the smallest infinite Lie subgroup  of $\mathcal{O}_n$ containing $\mathcal{P_n}$?

Basically, can $\mathcal{G_n}$ be a "continuous" extension of $\mathcal{P_n}$?

Comment: By "smallest" infinite Lie group, do you mean of the smallest cardinality?

Comment: I mean in the inclusion sense. Let me try to edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: There isn't a smallest in the inclusion sense. You can find families of nested infinite groups whose intersection is $\mathcal{P}_n$.

Comment: Are they Lie groups? Find me one Lie group that is contained in $\mathcal{G}_n$.

Comment: $\mathcal{G}_n$ is not smallest in the inclusion sense in that not every infinite Lie subgroup of $GL(n)$ which contains $\mathcal{P}_n$ also contains $\mathcal{G}_n$. For instance, the group $\{2^mP:P\in\mathcal{P}_n,m\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, is an infinite Lie subgroup, but it does not contain $\mathcal{G}_n$.

Comment: Thanks. I should add that I only want to look at unitary matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be an infinite Lie group satisfying $\mathcal{P}_n\le G\le\mathcal{O}_{n-1}$. Since $\mathcal{O}_{n-1}$ is compact, any $0$-dimensional subgroup is finite. Therefore, $G$ has dimension $\ge 1$. This implies that the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}=\text{Lie}(G)$ contains a nonzero element $\gamma\in\mathfrak{g}\subseteq\mathfrak{o}_{n-1}$. The set $\{\text{Ad}_P(\gamma):P\in\mathcal{P}_n\}$ spans $\mathfrak{o}_{n-1}$, so $\mathfrak{o}_{n-1}\subseteq\mathfrak{g}$ and thus $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{o}_{n-1}$. Since $\mathcal{P}_n$ (and thus $G$) contains an element in each connected component of $\mathcal{O}_{n-1}$, this implies $G=\mathcal{O}_{n-1}$. Thus there are no infinite proper Lie subgroups of $\mathcal{O}_{n-1}$ that contain $\mathcal{P}_n$.

$\mathcal{O}_{n-1}$ is an extension of $\mathcal{P}_n$, and it is in a limited sense "locally optimal", but there are other extensions. It would be natural, for instance, to require that the extension be compact and connected, and while it's still difficult to find a tenable notion of optimality, at least each finite groups has such an extension.

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate on why $\{\text{Ad}_P(\gamma):P\in\mathcal{P}_n\}$ spans $\mathfrak{o}_{n-1}$?

Comment: It might be possible to agrue that $\mathcal{O}_{n-1}$ doesn't seem like a natural extension for $\mathcal{P}_n$, but I was trying to search for a "continuous" group that has the symmetries of $\mathcal{P}_n$, and $\mathcal{G}_n$ was a natural candidate. I am trying to see if that position can be justified.

Comment: After projecting out $(1,\dots,1)$, we get the standard representation of $\mathcal{P}_n$, which acts by permuting the vertices $e^{(1)},\dots,e^{(n)}$ of a regular $n$-simplex centered at the origin. The matrices $$\left\{A^{(\alpha\beta)}_{ij}=e^{(\alpha)}_ie^{(\beta)}_j-e^{(\beta)}_ie^{(\alpha)}_j\right\}_{\alpha,\beta\in\{1,\dots,n\},\alpha\neq\beta}$$ contain a basis for $\mathfrak{o}_{n-1}$, and conjugating by elements of $\mathcal{P}_n$ acts transitively on $\{A^{(\alpha\beta)}\}$, so one (and thus any) nonzero $\text{Ad}_{\mathcal{P}_n}$-orbit spans $\mathfrak{o}_{n-1}$.

Answer (score -1):

No!  $\mathcal{P}_n$ is a 0-dimensional Lie group, and is clearly the smallest Lie group that contains $\mathcal{P}_n$.  It may be disconnected alright, but any subgroup of $O(n)$ containing $\mathcal{P}_n$ must be disconnected since $\mathcal{P}_n$ contains orientation-reversing elements.

Comment: Thanks. I am not very familiar with Lie groups to have realized this exception. I perhaps want to ask about the smallest infinite Lie group containing $\mathcal{P}_n$ then.

Comment: Then the answer is yes if you insist on putting it inside some compact Lie subgroups of $GL(n,\mathbb{F})$ and no otherwise, as @Kajelad shows in his answer.

Comment: Thanks. Can you confirm Kajelad's arguments? It will take me a while to verify them since I am not that familiar with Lie groups.